# Software for encryption of USB drive

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to encrypt my Sony USB pendrive.

Unfortunatelly my model is not supported by their own software, EasyLock.

Since I have to look for alternatives, I would like something that could work both on Windows and Ubuntu, because even though this pendrive is meant for carrying data to other PC's (university, pub PC's, etc) which probably run Windows, I would like the possibility to decrypt and access the data on Ubuntu as well, so a multiplatform solution would be welcome.

I am aware of Truecrypt, it works great and it doesn't require installation, I can just bring the executable with me but it requires admin privileges for mounting the volumes in Windows, and I really need to make sure I can decrypt the data whenever I need it, even if it is on a Windows PC running a limited user account.

Is there any multiplatform encryption software for full USB pendrive or even creation of individual volumes that can decrypt its contents on Ubuntu and also on Windows without requiring admin privileges?

Comment: admin as in the Windows UAC or the Password prompt for Ubuntu cause both can be managed by either by enabling it to run on startup on windows and adding truecrypt to list of sudoers in ubuntu

Comment: I am referring to the possibility of decrypting the data on a Windows PC running as a limited user and also be able to view the data on Ubuntu. I have reformulated the question to give some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit much, but you could always just zip all your files and then encrypt that with gpg. Would work with Linux and Windows.

Comment: Hum, I didn't know what gpg is so I had to search for a while, I can see that it encrypts files instead of disk volumes, actually it can be useful for protecting the most sensitive ones, which aren't that many. My remaining doubt is can it run on Windows without installation on the system (as Truecrypt and portableapps for example)?

Comment: I just found this: http://gpg4usb.cpunk.de/
A portable version of gpg4win. I think it will be enough, although whenever I don't need admin privileges I probably will continue to use Truecrypt.
Also 7zip can protect files and has a command-line version for Linux.